# How to downgrade Google Chrome from Beta to Stable?

Tags: google-chrome

I've been using Chrome Beta, but I don't like some of the recent changes. I'd like to downgrade to Chrome Stable. I tried to uninstall Chrome and reinstall the stable version, but now none of my extensions load because it says my profile is for a newer version of chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After  uninstalling Google Chrome from your computer ,Google Chrome leaves your profile information in your computer. The new profile will not be compatible with the older version. Now I'm going to redirect you to downgrade your chrome regarding this [information](http://techdows.com/2010/11/how-to-downgrade-to-older-version-of-chrome.html).

Before downgrading to older version of Chrome, backup your Chrome Profile to separate folder, export bookmarks too. You can backup [chrome extensions](http://techdows.com/2010/07/how-to-backup-and-restore-google-chrome-extensions.html) too.

### Downgrading to Older version of Chrome

1. Uninstall Google Chrome.
2. Since Chrome’s user profile will be left behind after Chrome uninstall, and this profile is not compatible with old Chrome version, so you should remove the profile also.

   #### Chrome profile location

   #### In Windows XP

   ```
   %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome
   ```

   #### In Windows 7

   ```
   %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome
   ```

   #### In OS X

   ```
   ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome
   ```
3. Now you can install older version of Google Chrome .